# React navigation and expo linking - Which prefixes to use?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, deep-linking

Im trying to understand prefixes more and on the react navigation page the documentation doesnt explain well I think.

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: ['mychat://', 'https://mychat.com'],
};
```

When having universal/deep links enabled:

1. Do I need to add both the app scheme AND the website url to prefixes like above?
2. What happens if I only add one or the other?